# To select one stream segment at a time for processing

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop

I have attached my stream order network image. I have five different order streams. There are several segments in each order. Now my problem is to select one segment of stream at a time for the further processing. I think this is not a big problem. But I am in trouble, I m using ArcGIS 10 and Python for processing. It would be great if you give some guidance to select each segment of stream at a time using python and GIS10.

[image]

Comment: Can you define 'segment of stream'? Are you trying to use segment like it is used in geometry (i.e a connected path between two endpoints) Or do you mean feature?

Comment: Are you able to post some of your current code so that we can see the direction you are heading in, please?

Comment: In my case, Segment of Stream means...starting point till the intersection point to another stream. In this case there are several 1,2,3,4 order stream segments and only one 5th order stream segement. I want to get like one segment from the origin till the confluence to another stream.

Comment: Do you have one seg. per order or multiple seg. per order?

Comment: I have multiple segments in one order. In this case I have more segments in 1-4 order and only one in 5th order

Comment: In your table do you have some sort of ID column/value that groups seg. together per order?

Comment: Actually When I create stream Order I will obtain like Value(Order) and Count. From that how can i differentiate each different segment in same order

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your river network is derived from a flow direction grid? Have a look at this [tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000056000000.htm) as it creates unique link IDs from your RASTER network.

Have you seen [RivEX](http://www.rivex.co.uk/) a VECTOR network processing tool? It can computer Strahler order from a vector network and assign the segment ID's you require.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your "further processing" involves, however the general idea for iterating through each segment follows these steps:

1. [convert your feature class to a feature layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000)
2. define a [cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000) to loop through your feature table
3. define the column to get values from
4. assign value to a variable and use that variable inside your [select layer by attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000) method/expression
5. do "further processing"
6. keep looping...